# Python Script to update all feature classes/datasets in gdb with search and update cursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, cursor

I have two geodatabases, one is a production sde database, the other is a backup in a local file geodatabase.  The script runs as a task once a month and is very resource intensive.  I am using ArcGIS for Desktop 10 SP 5.

What I would like to do is use a search and update cursor for each feature class in the database, including feature data sets; if there has been any change to the feature class; then just update the backup based on what is in the production instead of deleting it.

The example here shows how to update a feature class based on a field and changes to a field.  I would like to parse and update all feature classes in gdb2 if there is a change to a feature class in gdb1.  How can this script be modified to meet my needs?

```
import arcpy

#input feature class
fc2 = r"C:\temp\temp.gdb\fc2"
#target feature class
fc3 = r"C:\temp\temp.gdb\fc3"

#check field
checkField = "SRNumber"

#Get list of values in field from target feature class
checkValues = [r[0] for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc3, checkField)]

#Get list of fields
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields (fc2)]

#Get index of check field
index = fields.index (checkField)

#Create insert cursor for fc3 to allow appending of rows
inCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor (fc3, fields)

#Create search cursor to iterate input feature class
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor (fc2, fields)
#iterate
for row in cursor:
    #Get value to check
    checkValue = row[index]

    #Check if value is in target fc
    if checkValue in checkValues:
        #skip if value is in target fc
        continue

    #Insert row otherwise
    inCursor.insertRow(row)

#Clean up
del cursor
del inCursor
```

Comment: Are you on Desktop 10.0 SP5? I believe the `da` module was made available at 10.1. With [`walk`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/walk.htm) it would be simple to iterate over a GDB assuming the structures are identical.

Comment: I am not on 10.1  .da is not available in Desktop 10.0

Comment: Why not just replicate the feature class from production to development?

Answer (score 2):

As alexGIS already said, it would be easiest to create a replica between your SDE database and your local backup fileGDB

Make sure that your SDE database is versioned and all feature classes have a GlobalID. If you want to work with a fileGDB check-in/ check-out replicas is the right choise:
http://help.arcgis.com/EN/ARCGISDESKTOP/10.0/HELP/index.html#/Creating_a_check_out_replica/00270000002t000000/